# Escape HTML as well as \r \t and \n from a string

Tags: html, string, grails, replace

I am trying to index solar search from a built string in a code which has HTML tags. Any one knows how I can remove all the characters from the String.

Currently, I am using

```
answers << answer.feedback.replaceAll('\\<.*?>','')
```

I want to escape all the HTML characters and all the \n \t and \r. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to escape the html tags so that <span> becomes &lt;span&gt; or do you want to REMOVE the tags themselves. Your original question is ambiguous.

For the first scenario:

```
answer.feedback.encodeAsHTML()
```

(see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/codecs.html for further info)

Comment: No, I want to get rid of all the tags from html and form a plain text string separated with spaces.

Comment: well just add .replaceAll('[\n\r]', '') to the end